# docker-compose publishing port to host

Tags: node.js, docker, express, nginx, docker-compose

I'm playing a bit with docker, trying to expose an nginx container to the outside, serving 2 express app (not exposed).

I'm facing a problem, it looks like I can't access my nginx container from my host.

Here are my different files:

[image: Text]

Each app is, at the moment fairly simple:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 80;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const os = require("os");
  const hostname = os.hostname();
  
  res.json({hostname: hostname, message: 'Hello from auth'}); //or Hello from health
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

The Nginx config file I'm using:

```
server {
    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass http://health/;
    }

    location /api/auth {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        proxy_pass http://auth/;
    }
}
```

and finally the docker-compose file

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    auth:
        build:
            context: ./auth
    health:
        build:
            context: ./health
    nginx:
        restart: always
        build:
            context: ./nginx
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
```

When I open a cli from the nginx container, I'm able to query both my express app through nginx:
[image]

But when I'm trying from my host web browser, it looks like I can't connect to the nginx container.
Any ideas ?

PS
Here are the Dockerfiles:

express app

```
FROM node:14-alpine
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 80
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

nginx

```
FROM nginx
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Comment: You are using the port 8080 in the request url when opening it in the browser?

Comment: What's the actual error you get?  You included a PNG file in the question; is the image-handling code that produces that important to the question?  What is in `nginx/Dockerfile`?

Comment: Thanks for you answers.

Yeah, I am querying http://localhost:8080

I did edit the first message to include both Dockerfile

Comment: The error I get is the ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error from Chrome

Comment: I'm able to get a response via curl from my host tho:

        C:\Users\bastien>curl 127.0.0.1:8080
        {"hostname":"257de83ed69d","message":"Hello from health"}
        C:\Users\bastien>curl 127.0.0.1:8080/api/auth
        {"hostname":"60d2ec0d9681","message":"Hello from auth"}`